# SmtpException in ASP.NET application with remote browser

Tags: asp.net, email, smtpclient

I have an ASP.NET 4 application running under IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008 machine. The app uses the `System.Net.Mail` classes to send email through an SMTP server. I am using port 587 for SSL connection. When I browse the application from within the server, emails are sent OK. However, when I browse to the application from a remote (client) computer, email sending fails with a `SmtpException` having `StatusCode = GeneralFailure`. The message says that the SMTP server could not be connected and there is an inner `SocketException`.

The server is running the F-Secure antivirus system. I tried disabling it, but the errors persist.

Email sending works or not depending on how I am accessing the web server:

- If I browse to http://myapp.mydomain.com from a remote client, using the server's publicly-available DNS name, then it fails.
- If I browse to http://193.144.xxx.xxx/myapp from a remote client, using the server's public IP address plus the name of the web application in IIS, then it also fails.
- If I browse to http://internal-name/myapp from a remote client, using the server's internal name in the domain plus the name of the web application in IIS through a VPN, then it works!
- If I browse from an interactive session on the server itself, no matter how I do it (public DNS name, public IP address, internal domain name or just `localhost`), then it works too.
  How is it possible that mail sending works when browsed from the server but not when browsed remotely? In both cases it is the same server sending the emails.

And if I browse the application on my development machine from within Visual Studio, then it all works fine.

Please see this too: https://serverfault.com/questions/845606/iis-randomly-returning-inet-e-resource-not-found

**EDIT**. The server has a private IP address to use internally at work, as well as a public IP address that the public DNS resolves to. This public IP address is not configured on the server itself; rather, it is a forwarding service carried out by our Internet access provider. Is it possible that the SMTP server is baffled by the fact that a connection request is arriving from a client that claims to have an address, but then has a name that resolves to a different address?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. Are you sure you are comparing apples to apples? Meaning are you running http://localhost from within the server compared to the url used outside the server

Comment: No; I am using exactly the same URL to access the server in both cases. Please see also this: https://serverfault.com/questions/845606/iis-randomly-returning-inet-e-resource-not-found; the two issues may be related.

Comment: The easiest way to find out if F-Secure is the problem is by temporarily disabling the program and test it.
I have run into problems with SMTP in the past and the solution usually was to make sure "app server" has the right permissions in the "SMTP server".

Comment: I will do that on Monday. However, if F-Secure was interfering with the SMTP connection, it should do it regardless of where I am browsing the web app from. But it only fails when I browse from a remote client.

Comment: Apparently, F-Secure is not to blame. I just tried sending emails with the anti-virus disabled and the errors are still the same.

Comment: I will check the permissions. Try adding temporarily the "app server machine user" as an admin in the "smtp server".

Comment: I don't have access to the SMTP server, unfortunately. It is managed by a different organisation and I can't change its setup.

Comment: You can try to send a test email outside of the ASP .Net environment, from a source like a PowerShell script or a Console Apo or maybe LinqPad.

Comment: Also, make sure EnableSsl is set to true.

Comment: SSL is properly set. I will try to send an email from PowerShell; good idea, thanks.

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Email from a shell on the server sends fine. But, then again, the web app works fine when I connect to the server through the private IP address.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much investigation, we have found the root problem. Our Internet access provider found a configuration error in the NAT tables that mapped the public IP address to our server's internal IP address. This caused some requests to be dropped. They have fixed the configuration and things work well now.

Thanks to all who helped with this.